# Setting canvas size from textfield

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas

I´m trying to create a canvas who's size is being set by user. User inserts size of the canvas to two text fields with names `width` and `height`. After clicking submit button canvas is created and width is set but height is still 0. Any ideas ?

```
submit.onclick = function() {
    var width = document.getElementsByName("width")[0].value;
    var height = document.getElementsByName("height").value;
    createCanvas(width,height);
    $("#frame").remove();

    function createCanvas(width, height) {
        var selector = document.getElementById('canvas-wrapper');
        selector.innerHTML = '<canvas id="cnvs"></canvas>';
        var canvas = document.getElementById("cnvs");
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Don't you see the obvious difference between lines 2 and 3? Hint: Array index

Comment: Sorry Im new to the javascript Im still learning.

Comment: so ... did you see the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is here:

```
var width = document.getElementsByName("width")[0].value;
var height = document.getElementsByName("height").value;
```

I see you're using jQuery, why don't you take advantage of it, if you're loading it anyway?

```
var width = $('#yourWidthFormElement').val();
var height = $('#yourHeightFormElement').val();
```

the html for this would be:

```
<input type="text" id="yourWidthFormElement" placeholder="width" />
<input type="text" id="yourHeightFormElement" placeholder="height" />
```

I'm assuming the "submit" variable is declared and holds a dom element